# Co-Authoring excel doc changes views for hidden sheets with auto save is turned on. Is ther a VBA code we can use to stop this?

Tags: excel, vba, hidden, autosave

We currently have a Co-Authoring document that uses VBA to hide/unhide sheets based on selection on the overview page.  15 individuals use this spreadsheet daily and are making updates to various tabs at any point in time.  When we turn on the Auto-Save, the hidden sheets views will change for everyone simultaneously everyone and is causing issues.  If we turn off the Auto-Save, then we are running into the error messages - this document cannot be saved and to save a copy; therefore, we'd prefer to keep the Auto-Save turned on.

How can we stop the view from changing for the additional sheets and not just the overview page?  Is there a VBA code that could be used?

We've tried to used the Sheet view, but this only works on the Main Overview page, it has no effect on the additional tabs.

We've also tried to select - See just mine; but again, this only works on the tab you have open at the time.  It does not stop additional tabs from appearing/disappearing based on others selections.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.